# Can't get socket.io event from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I'm making a Socket.IO app, and trying to add a client-side listener for an event, in addition to a listener I already have. The problem is that the existing code is quite hard for me to make sense of, as I didn't write sections of it and am new to Socket.IO, so I don't know where to put my second event listener.

I've tried adding it in right before and after my first event listener, with no success.

The existing code, with one socket.on listener, besides 'connect':

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io();
  socket.on('connect', function(){
  var id = socket.io.engine.id;
      document.getElementById("os").innerHTML = id
      });
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val())
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;

    });


    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      var form = $('#m').val();
      //logic for commands 
      var help = /#help/;
      var kill = /#kill/;
      var admin = /SUDO/;
      var private = /#to/;
      var one = help.test(msg);
      var two = kill.test(msg);
      var three = admin.test(msg);
      var four = private.test(msg);

      if (one == true) {
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text('[SYSTEM]: The "#help" command has been activated. The following is an automated response and the user message which activated #help will appear below it in the chat stream. '));
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text("[#HELP]: This message is a brief overview of how to use Megaphone: type a message into the bar above, and hit enter to send it. Refresh the window to clear messages, and to leave, simply close the tab.")); 
        function delay(ms, cb) { setTimeout(cb, ms) }
        document.title = "New Message!";
        audio.play();
        delay(5000, function() {
        document.title = "Megaphone";
        })

      } if (two == true && three == true) {
         location = "https://google.com"

      } if (two == true && three == false) {
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(' [SYSTEM]: ATTEMPTED ACCESS TO AN ADMIN COMMAND DETECTED. THE COMMAND CANNOT BE USED WITHOUT AN ADMIN PASSPHRASE.'));
        function delay(ms, cb) { setTimeout(cb, ms) }
        document.title = "New Message!";
        audio.play();
        delay(5000, function() {
        document.title = "Megaphone";
        })

      } if (three == true) {
        var adminmsg = msg.split('SUDO')[1]
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(' [ADMIN]: ' + adminmsg));
        function delay(ms, cb) { setTimeout(cb, ms) }
        document.title = "New Message!";
        audio.play();
        delay(3000, function() {
        document.title = "Megaphone";
        })

      } if  (four == true) {
        var privatemessage = msg.split('#to')[0];
        var recipientid = msg.split('#to')[1];
        socket.emit('private message', { recipient: recipientid, message: privatemessage });


      } else {
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(' [USER]: ' + msg));
        function delay(ms, cb) { setTimeout(cb, ms) }
        document.title = "New Message!";
        audio.play();
        delay(5000, function() {
        document.title = "Megaphone";
        })
      };
    });
    });
```

The event listener I'd like to add:

```
socket.on("dm", function(data) {
    alert(data.description);
}
```

Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/about.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000. Megaphone is functional.');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.info(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}]`);
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.info(`Client gone [id=${socket.id}]`);
  });
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('private message', ({ recipient, message }) => {
     io.to(recipient).emit("dm", {description: message});
     console.info(message + ' ' + recipient)
})
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

When I insert the second event listener right before or after the first, it doesn't seem to work as there's no alert.

Comment: can you show your node js code too

Comment: that should be it!

Comment: can you confirm the 'private message' event is being sent from a browser and is executing at the server code.
Then confirm the 'recipient' field in private message event is a valid browser client that is able to receive the 'dm' event